# "BitCoin-QT" Core Upgrade - PRIOR Steps?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I plan an upgrade of an old "BitCoin-QT" Core client wallet from 'V0.7 2-beta' to the latest Bitcoin Core 0.15 (Oct 2017).

I've got good instruction on the upgrade path - but my questions is:

- Besides backing up my ‘wallet.dat’ (in case something goes wrong in the upgrade) - is there anything ELSE I should consider in this big Upgrade leap ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

bitcoin-qt 0.8 changed the database structure. Bitcoin Core 0.15 changed the database structure again. There is no direct database structure upgrade path from bitcoin-qt 0.7.x to Bitcoin Core 0.15. You will have to upgrade to a version between 0.8 and 0.14 first before you can upgrade to Bitcoin Core 0.15. I recommend first updating to Bitcoin Core 0.14.2, letting it build the databases and sync, then upgrading to Bitcoin Core 0.15.0.1.

See also: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.15.0.md#how-to-upgrade

Comment: Thanks! - Regarding my ‘wallet.dat’ file in this 2 step process (i) V0.7 2-beta' TO Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 (ii) Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 to Bitcoin Core 0.15.X - Does the .Dat file need to be put back in after phase (i) and resynched ? OR can I put the .Dat file back in after phase (ii) and synch ? Cheers

Comment: You do not need to move your wallet.dat file at all. There is no need to remove it nor to put it back in the datadir.